# Does pump durability affects Blight rewards?

Tags: path-of-exile

Does the durability of the pump affect the rewards you get from the chests afterwards? Obviously, the goal is to prevent the pump from reaching 0 durability and being ultimately destroyed -- but what happens to the rewards if I finish a pump with only a sliver of durability left vs no damage to the pump at all?

Comment: Didn't noticed any correlation. It's just HP, it's more in harder event. Event will instantly ends if HP reach 0 and you keep rewards (chests) what appears until then. Idea of "flawless" victory is somewhat bad: it force you to still feel a looser unless it's perfect. I don't recall when GGG ever tried it before, so should be no reason to have it now. More chests = more loot, but *quality* of loot is questionable.

Comment: Check out this [great findings](https://www.reddit.com/r/pathofexile/comments/8vsxaq/timer_has_strong_impact_on_incursion_loot/) in Incursion league. In Blight you get "guaranteed" mirror drop if you defend 5 pumps with 100% hp.. in a single map.

Comment: @Sinatr This is false.

Comment: @duskwuff, you are right, I should have added word "sarcasm" somewhere. I thought it sounds non-realistic enough, since there is only 1 pump per map.. or it could be more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does the durability of the pump affect the rewards you get from the chests afterwards?

No. It can't -- the reward nodes at the end of each lane appear, and can be looted, as soon as the lane is completed. This can occur while monsters are still active in other lanes, and are thus still able to damage the pump.

Comment: Playing devil's advocate here. It's logical what you wrote, sure.. what if loot in spawned chests depends on pump health at the moment of chest spawn? What if loot generated at that moment of spawn and not when you open chest (where pump may be destroyed already)?